# Bayesian inference in independent but not identically distributed examples

Tags: bayesian, posterior

Let data $\lbrace X_i \rbrace _{i=1}^m$ be examples sampled independently from normals, $X_i \sim N(\mu,\sigma_i)$. Variances are known but mean $\mu$ is unknown. Let prior on $\mu$ be also a Gaussian, $\mu \sim N(\mu_1,\sigma_0)$. Can I have a closed form for posterior distribution of $\mu$ given data? or any suggestions? If data was iid from Gaussian, since likelihood and prior are both gaussian, then posterior would be Gaussian with parameters given in closed form.

Comment: Just derive the posterior and you will find the answer!